# How can I do a Line break

Tags: php

How can I do a line break every 5 scores? I have the following code but it shows me all the results in one line, and it needs to start a new line every 5 scores, without using a table.

```
<?php session_start();
include ("conexion.php");    
?>

<?php

$correo=$_SESSION['s_username'];
$sql ="SELECT nombre_catalogo FROM catalogos WHERE email = '$correo'";
$res=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>";
$fecha = array();

while ($row20 = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

    $fecha[] = $row20['nombre_catalogo'];            

}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Name</td>";
foreach($fecha as $fec) {
    echo "<td>" . $fec . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fec . "</td>";

}
?>
```

For example, If I have 13 scores on my db it shows me one line like

```
*************
```

But its needs to be this way

```
*****
*****
***
```

Comment: you can use a modulus/modulo http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Use a loop or a modulus.

Comment: Use chunk_array ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: ...now the question's getting "too broad" ;-) as in too many possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

[*array_chunk*](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-chunk.php) can be a solution.

```
while ($row20 = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $fecha[] = $row20['nombre_catalogo'];
}


$fecha = array_chunk($fecha, 5);
foreach($fecha as $data)
{
    foreach($data as $fec)
    {
        echo $fec;
    }
    # echo implode('', $data); // implode also can be used instead of nested loop.
    echo '</br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it is the idea but do you know how to reproduce also  the  <td>.? Because if I do this: foreach($data as $fec)
    {
        echo "<td>".$fec"</td>";
    }.................it still show me one line

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `str_split()` [PHP DOC](http://php.net/str_split)

See my example here:

```
<?php
    $string = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    // split the string every 5 chars, return as array
    $result = str_split($string, 5);
    // now create new string by imploding, with linebreak as glue
    $result1 = implode(PHP_EOL, $result);
    // OR
    $result2 = implode("\r\n", $result);

    print_r($result1);
    print_r($result2);
?>
```