# How to return the results of my query in rows

Tags: php, html, html-table

This is my query, and it is working fine, but how do I have the results returned in an HTML TABLE. for example I want the first 5 results on row 1 the next 5 on row 2 and so on. Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
<?php
$servername = "XXX";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM manufacturer LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo  '<td><a href="index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info& 
manufacturer_id='. $row["manufacturer_id"] .'"><img src="image/' .  
$row["image"] .'"></a></td>';
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Use of modulo operator?

Comment: array_chunk should be easier imo : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: ^ I'm having a [*"Déjà vue..."*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44164304/1415724).

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hopefully [August C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819720/august-c) is [NotThatGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4449515/notthatguy) :)

Comment: @Thamilan *lol* - No, it's not what I meant *haha!* - it was about the "modulo/array_chunk" thing ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$servername = "XXX";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,   $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn- >connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM manufacturer LIMIT 10  OFFSET 0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
$i=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
If($i==5){
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
$i=0;
}
echo  '<td><a href="index.php? route=product/manufacturer/info& 
manufacturer_id='. $row["manufacturer_id"] .'">.   <img src="image/' .  
$row["image"] .'"></a></td>';
$i++;
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```